# Check condition of two columns in same table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dup_uld
(IN DPD_ID int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE CNT INT;
    DECLARE MESSAGE_TEXT varchar(80);   

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CNT   
    FROM doctor_personal_details    
    WHERE ULD_ID = DPD_ID;

    IF(CNT = 0 ) THEN     
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'THIS ULD_ID ALREADY EXISTS';
    END IF;  
END;
```

**Column1:**

DPD_ID

1

2

3

**Column2**

ULD_ID

3

3

5

**My question** 
ULD_ID is not to be repeat each DPD_ID values to specify one ULD_ID value

Comment: To my mind, the entire premise of the question is flawed. What if someone runs an INSERT while this query is executing? The standard approach is to execute an INSERT. If the INSERT fails then you know the data already exists.

Comment: My question is if i give values it needs to check 2 columns  for example see above there are two columns in 1st row DPD_ID =1 ULD_ID=3 Condition satisfies 2nd row DPD_ID =2 ULD_ID=3 ,now ULD_ID is repeating now exception needs to occur

Comment: @gobi when did it throw exception?

Comment: @sagar tq for ur reply, When i give same value again in ULD_ID exception needs to occur

Comment: Through procedure or trigger??

Comment: through trigger